# jenkins env variables not recognized

Tags: angularjs, jenkins

I have problems with Jenkins when I am programming a task that executes a windows command. The problem is always the same:

In this example I am trying to publish an angular application for production:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\angular-test-publish-IIS>ng build --prod 
>   "ng" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable. C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\angular-test-publish-IIS>exit 9009 
>   Build step 'Ejecutar un comando de Windows' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

I have the same problem with all the commands, I have to specify the full path.

Some commands work correctly but in the case of angular CLI it doesn't work with the full path:

When I put the path completely for ng command I have this output ("C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm" run ng test --single-run test):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\angular-test-publish-IIS>"C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm" run ng test --single-run test 
>   npm WARN lifecycle npm is using C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe but there is no node binary in the current PATH. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
>
> spa@0.0.0 ng C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\angular-test-publish-IIS
>   ng "test" "test"
>   "node" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
>   programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! spa@0.0.0 ng: `ng "test" "test"`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the spa@0.0.0 ng script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-11-09T12_01_21_841Z-debug.log
>   Build step 'Ejecutar un comando de Windows' marked build as failure
>   Finished: FAILURE

Comment: you need to add the environment variable in the settings of jenkin

Comment: yes, i found it and all work well